# NSScrollview does not honor system preferences for scroll bars (when scrolling), while I override the -tile method

Tags: macos, nsscrollview, tile, scroller

Below is my code that overlays a control on the horizontal scrollbar.

```
- (void)tile
{
    [super tile];
    if (subControl)
    {
        NSRect subControlFrame = [subControl frame];

        NSScroller *horizontalScroller = [self horizontalScroller];

        NSRect scrollerFrame = [horizontalScroller frame];

        // adjust control position here in the scrollview coordinate space
        subControlFrame.origin.x = scrollerFrame.origin.x;
        subControlFrame.origin.y = scrollerFrame.origin.y;
        subControlFrame.size.height = scrollerFrame.size.height;
        // move controls
        [subControl setFrame:subControlFrame];

        NSRect subControlFrame2 = [subControl frame];

        scrollerFrame.origin.x += subControlFrame2.size.width;

        scrollerFrame.size.width -= subControlFrame2.size.width;

        [horizontalScroller setFrame:scrollerFrame];
    }
}
```

After the line

```
    [subControl setFrame:subControlFrame];
```

it stops responding to system preferences??